# SpecificAvro Serdes without registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Is there a way to configure avro serdes without the http calls to the avro-registry?

Basically we'd like to limit the registry to our CI/CD when building or releasing components. The schema-registry maven plugin would be used to check backward compatibility prior to registering a schema. Similarly, the consuming projects would download the latest schemas for code generation using the same maven plugin.

Given the CI/CD would enforce the avro compatibility checks prior to releasing, we don't quite understand why we would need to maintain a coupling between our components running in production and the schema registry.

Comment: You would need to write your own deserializers that are able to use a specific serde object and ignore the schema ID.

Comment: Maybe you want to try setting `auto.register.schemas` to false, though